# Get changed files from svn command line between two dates

Tags: svn, diff

I need to get the changed files list between two dates in SVN.

I have used the below command..

```
svn diff -r{2011-10-12}:{2011-10-28} --summarize https://svn.blah.com/../  > output.txt
```

from some reason the files modified on 28-10-2011 are not populated in the output text file.

Could please give the exact command to extract the files list between the two dates (inclusive of from and to dates)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

this is normal, when you give the date `{2011-10-28}` it means "on midnight"... thus specify one day more for the end of the range.