# How to get only specific extension files changed from svn command line between two dates

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

Can someone please help me how to get only specific file extension(for example: .sql) changed from svn command line between two dates

Following command gets all files

```
svn diff -r{2017-10-12}:{2017-10-28} --summarize https://svn.blah.com/../  > output.txt
```

Comment: [I think this might answer your question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9189786/get-changed-files-from-svn-command-line-between-two-dates)

Comment: @NiranjanReddyI did refer it, but I want only specific file extension, for example how to list of all SQL files changed between two dates using svn command line?

Comment: svn diff -r{2017-10-12}:{2017-10-28} --summarize https://svn.blah.com/../ | grep *.svn > output.txt

Comment: @M005 What do you think about the answer ?

Comment: @LaurentH. it helped me !! sorry for delay to accept answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to pass the ouput of your `svn diff` command to either `find` (for Windows) or `grep` (for Linux) command, as follows:

1. For Windows:  `svn diff -r{2017-10-12}:{2017-10-28} --summarize https://svn.blah.com/../ | find ".sql" > output.txt`
2. For Linux:  `svn diff -r{2017-10-12}:{2017-10-28} --summarize https://svn.blah.com/../ | grep .sql  > output.txt`

Comment: Why not `--search` and `--search-and`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`--search` and `--search-and` command-line options of `svn log` command](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.c.log.html). You could also use [TortoiseSVN Revision Log Dialog](https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-showlog.html#tsvn-dug-showlog-filter) to filter required usernames.